# Size of my ImageViews is changing between different screen size. RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm using a `RelativeLayout` in the layout of my app. 
When I'm choosing different screen size, my ImageViews doesn't keep the same ratio. I'm defining my layout size in hardcoded `dp`. I think the problem come from the fact that I'm using `dp` to define my layout and because of that when I'm using my app on different screen with different dpi.

Do you have tips to make my app fits different screen sizes with the same ratio?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Without a snippet of your layout is really hard to understand the issue, also adding some screenshots of the difference between screen size might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the height and width of your parent Relative layout , and define each child view with a relation to each other , Or you can move to constraint layout or Linear layout. You should add you layout XML file to understand the actual issue